# Why chrome.debugger.attach callback function should be used like cb.bind(null, ....)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a **chrome extension**. Now I'm coming into a problem of **chrome.debugger** that the debugger **only can attach one http request**. the **rest** request of the tab can't be detected. I find this is caused by the callback function.

According to the [official manual](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html#method-attach), using the `chrome.debugger.attach`, when the 3rd parameter is a callback function. In **live-headers**, the attach code is this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.debugger.attach({tabId:tab.id}, version,
        onAttach.bind(null, tab.id));
});

var version = "1.0";

function onAttach(tabId) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }

    chrome.windows.create(
        {url: "headers.html?" + tabId, type: "popup", width: 800, height: 600});
}
```

In my code, I call attach like this(**just not using bind**):

```
myAttach = function () {....};

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.debugger.attach({tabId:tab.id}, version, myAttach)
});
```

When I using the former format, everything is OK. I can't understand the difference and the result.

**Problem**: when I use the **second method**, there will be no more `Network.responseReceived` or `Network.requestWillBeSent` messages received. I have tried to use [getTargets](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html#method-getTargets) and find the debugger attach of the tab is detached. When I return to the **first method**, every thing is ok.

Sorry for my poor english

Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't understand the question... (What happens when you do what and what should be happening and what is the problem ?)

Comment: BTW, your seconde "attempt" isn't even valid JS. You should see errors in the console log.

Comment: sorry for my poor english. The problem is that when I use the callback

Comment: sorry for my poor english. The problem is that when I use the callback function **without** `cb.bind(null, args)`, the debugger can just attach the tab for **once**, when visit other link in this tab, the debugger is not valid, no `Network.responseReceived` or `Network.requestWillBeSent` will be received. @ExpertSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably ignore what the `bind` function does (and why it makes all the difference in this case).   When in doubt about anything WebDev-related, you can head for **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)**:

Regarding [function **bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> Creates a new function that, when called, has its 'this' keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

---

So, what is the difference between your way and the docs' way ?

**Your way:**

```
function myAttach() {...}   <--  A function that expects no arguments
...
chrome.debugger.attach(
    ..., 
    myAttach   <-- 'myAttach()' is called, with no arguments
);                 and therefore no way to refer to the tab's id
```

**The docs' way:**

```
function onAttach(tabId) {...}   <-- A function that expects 1 argument
...
chrome.debugger.attach(
    ..., 
    onAttach.bind(null, tab.id)   <-- Creates a new function, let's name it "tmpFunc".
);                                    'tmpFunc()' is called, with no arguments
```

But what is `tmpFunc` ?

(It is not exactly that, but) you can think of it as a function that expects no arguments and when called executes `onAttach`, passing `tab.id` as its first argument. Thus it is possible for `onAttach` to refer to the tabId (and do stuff with it).